# White to force the end of the game in two moves

Tags: problems

I found this hilarious problem and hope people will have fun solving it:

Niels Hoeg, Skakbladet 1907

```
[FEN "8/8/6p1/5pP1/5P1K/5PpP/4p2p/2Q2Bkr w - - 0 1"]
```

White to end the game in two moves.

In this case, that means that white plays moves so that, no matter what black moves, the game is finished after *black's* second move at the latest.

Comment: We do allow puzzle questions like this, don't we?

Comment: We sure do! We've done a few other tactics/strategy problems before

Comment: As [Noam](http://chess.stackexchange.com/users/8860/noam-d-elkies) pointed out, my try doesn't work. ​ (I completely missed gxf2.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very nice puzzle! Looks like the solution is as follows:

```
[FEN "8/8/6p1/5pP1/5P1K/5PpP/4p2p/2Q2Bkr w - - 0 1"]

1. Qe1 g2 (1... exf1=Q 2. Kxg3 Qxe1#) (1... exf1=R 2. Qxg3#) (1... exf1=N 2. Qf2+ Kxf2 (2... gxf2)) (1... exf1=B 2. Kxg3) 2. Bxe2# 1-0
```

Interestingly, in the different lines, following results are achieved:

- White gives a checkmate
- Black gives a checkmate
- White is stalemated
- Black is stalemated

Comment: Yes, four different promotions, leading to four different outcomes of the game. I had never seen anything like it :-)

Comment: Yes, very striking.  Is the Black pawn on g3 needed for soundness?  If not then normally one would remove it; the extra variation 1 . . . g2 2 Bxe2# feels less like a bonus than a distraction from the theme.

Comment: Well spotted! As far as I can tell, the g3 pawn is not needed...

Comment: Thanks, but later I noticed that the pawn can't be removed because without it **Ricky Demer**'s try 1 Qc5+ Kxf1 2 Qf2+ would be a cook.  True, this cook can be eliminated in other ways without adding the 1 . . . g2  variation; but there'd still be a dual in the variation 1 Qe1 exf1=B when White could choose between stalemating (2 Kg3, as in the solution) and being stalemated (2 Qf2+, the dual).  So if the 1 . . . g2 line is a distraction it's an unavoidable one.